# Como importar Jquery externo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Boa tarde, meus caros

Estou com um problema na importação do javascript externo, (no caso biblioteca Jquery)

Os arquivos estão na pasta correcta mas quando chamo pelo src="" nada acontece.

Deste ja agradeço ajuda.

[image: print de tela]

Comment: jquery.min.js deve vir antes de bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Meu caro Maurivan, 
Salvaste a patria meu herói, funcionou.
obrigado

Comment: Por que não funcionou na ordem anterior?

Comment: Simplesmente porque bootstrap tem jQuery como dependência e não o contrário.

Recomendo verificar a documentação: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included

Comment: Ah sim, muito Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exatamente como foi dito pelo colega Maurivan.
Quando utilizamos o Bootstrap devemos realizar a importação dos arquivos css e dos arquivos js.

No caso dos arquivos js devemos obedecer a ordem da precedência de quem depende de quem. Que neste caso o Bootstrap depende do JQuery, então ele deve vir primeiro na ordem de carregamento.

Comment: Valeu, não fazia ideia que tinha uma ordem, por isso não funcionava